# Can I filter a query for a subquery object size?

Tags: soql, subquery

What I'm trying to accomplish is to retrieve some Account records where a subquery item size is > 0

For example:

```
Select id, (select id from relatedItems__r) from Account where (relatedItems__r.totalsize > 0)
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without looping through the entire list in Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL isn't really well suited for what you're asking.

If you're only looking for the Account Id, then flipping the query around (so that you have `FROM Related_Item__c` instead of `FROM Account`) can work if you use `GROUP BY`. We can also "trick" Salesforce into building a `Map<Id, SObject>` for us by taking advantage of *aliasing*.

```java
// Since you're only looking for parents with > 0 children, you don't need
//   to use "HAVING COUNT(AccountId) > 0" here
// ...but you could use it if you're looking for parents with at least X children
//   no more than Y children, or between X and Y children
Map<Id, SObject> sobjMap = new Map<Id, SObject>(
    [SELECT AccountId Id FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId]
);
```

The obvious limitation here is that without any filters, this would query every related record that you have. Query selectivity and the 50k query row limit would be a concern.

If you need more than just the Account Id, then you'd need to use a second query and feed it the results of the first query. E.g. `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :sobjMap.keySet()]`

Beyond that, the only other approach I can currently see that doesn't involve explicit looping is to use a rollup summary field to get the count of child records on each `Account` ([the DLRS tool](https://install.salesforce.org/products/dlrs) can help if your child object isn't in a Master-Detail relationship with Account).

This would allow you to just add a simple filter. `[SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Child_Count_Rollup__c > 0]`

Comment: Flipping the query around would be a solution but in this current case it would force me to pretty much write the component from scratch, so that isn't an option sadly.
I'll probably use either a loop or two queries filtering out the unwanted records. Thank you for the input!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId HAVING COUNT(Id) > 2)
```

WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId HAVING COUNT(Id) > 2): This is the condition to filter the accounts. It uses a subquery to select the AccountId from the Contact object, groups them by AccountId, and then applies the condition HAVING COUNT(Id) > 2 to retrieve only those accounts with more than two contacts associated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you try to actually run this query, you'll find that this is invalid syntax. Semi-joins cannot use `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, or `HAVING` (though to be fair, this does not appear to be mentioned in the documentation).